# PostgreSQL Timezone configuration changes

Tags: postgresql, timezone

I have change time zone as explained in this http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datetime-config-files.html but changes are not showing in sql results. How can i reload timezone values.

Comment: Most likely you use the `TIMESTAMP` type, which defaults to `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`. Please include you table definition (`CREATE TABLE`), your PostgreSQL version & your query (you should use `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` or simply `timestamptz` - this type stores its values within UTC & clients get the offsetted value according to the actual `TimeZone` configuration).

Comment: @pozs times are store in Database in UTC format. What i need is to change offset for a specific timezone. Ex SELECT TIMESTAMP '2001-02-16 12:00:00' AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Colombo'; Result GMT+5.30. I want to change this to GMT+6.00 because of Day light saving.

Comment: Did you restart PostgreSQL after the changes? What version of PostgreSQL?

Comment: Yes I restarted. 9.1 is the version. i am running a Mac Version. "PostgreSQL 9.1.4 on x86_64-apple-darwin12.0.0, compiled by i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00), 64-bit"